# Can set id but can't set the class to svg

Tags: javascript

I have created a svg dynamic but I can't set the class name to this svg.

```
var circle = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
circle.setAttribute("cx", 6);
circle.setAttribute("cy", 6);
circle.setAttribute("r", 4);
circle.setAttribute( 'id', 'special'); (this method is working), but

circle.className("abc"); **is not working**
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... because that's not how you set a class name?

```
circle.className = "abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use in this way:

```
circle.className = "abc";
```

There isn't a method with this namee (className) but it is a attribute of element: in this case you must use the = symbol  :)

Regards,
Kevin